# maps.google API max 256 visible markers

Tags: google-maps-markers

Breaks my head everytime I think about a solution:
I can process (placing) more than 256 markers using google.maps.Map(), each with an eventListener (InfoWindow), but I can only make max 256 markers visible.
I toggle markers with a few buttons.
If I go over 256, the markers will be visible but not clickable anymore (breaks the functionality) and a reload of the page is neccessary.
[image: part of the map]

[image: when clicked on a marker]

```
var arrayLength = points.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var marker = addMarker(points[i], map);
    marker.setMap(map);
}

function addMarker(point, map) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var iconColor = (point.type == 'circle') ? "/images/circle.png" : "/images/pointer_" + point.clr.replace("#","") + ".png";
    var size = (point.type == 'circle') ? '20' : '10';
    var goldStar = {
        url: iconColor,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(size,15)
    };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point.latlng,
        title: "" + point.crDate + "",
        icon: goldStar,
        visible: false,
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.close();
        infowindow.setContent( 
            '<div style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;" onClick="window.opener.getQIDData('
            + point.qid 
            + ',\'\',' 
            + point.t 
            +',\'' 
            + point.afd 
            + '\')">'
            + point.crDate 
            + '<br>' 
            + point.afd 
            + '<br>' 
            + point.pers 
            + '<br>' 
            + point.qid 
            +'</div>' );
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
}

var markerGroups = {
    "l-m": [],
    "o-m": [],
    "o-m2": [],
    "r-m": [],
    "r-b": [],
    "r-bb": [],
    "p-2": [],
    "p-3": [],
    "a-i": [],
    "a-b": [],
    "a-bl": [],
    "a-on": [],
    "a-old": [],
    "a-youri": [],
    "sms": [],
    "l-1": [],
    "l-2": []
};

//    'type' is the selected (pressed) button, corresponding to the markerGroups 
function toggleGroup(type) {
    var count = 0;
    //    buttons with .selected have no points visible (counter-intuitive, sorry ;-))
    $("." + type).toggleClass("selected");
    for (var group in markerGroups) {
        if (!$("." + group).hasClass("selected")) {
            count = (count + markerGroups[group].length);
        }
    }
    
    //  clear all markers before putting new on screen if count > 256
    if (count > 256) {
        for (var group in markerGroups) {
            markerGroups[group].forEach(marker => marker.setVisible(false));
            $("." + group).addClass("selected");
        }
    }

    for (var group in markerGroups) {
        var state = ($("." + group).hasClass("selected"))
            ?   false
            :   true;
        if (type == group) {
            markerGroups[group].forEach(marker => marker.setVisible(state));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(size,15)
```

broke the code. Has nothing to do with maximum eventlisteners.
Making more than 256 markers visible with scaled images is impossible.

Thank you for reading.